# Style suggestion + how to do?

Tags: page-numbering, page

I'm a very beginner in LaTeX (and I have no much time to improve my knowledge...).

I'm writing a document, below you can find a picture of the document, and the code.

Question 1)
what to do with the empty odd page between two chapter? Clearly I want it, but the question is: should I have the number? Should I show the title of the chapter? Should I show the row? Is it better to have just a blank page? Or just the number with the row, and no title? Or just the number?

So... I need a suggestion :D

Question 2: 
how to make what you suggest to do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,b5paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[b5paper,twoside,top=2.8cm,bottom=2.8cm,left=3cm,right=1.7cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}\addtolength{\headwidth}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ #1}{}}

\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries}}

\cfoot{}                     

\setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}

\begin{document}

\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\bfseries Introduction}

Blablablablabla

\chapter{chapter 1}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\bfseries chapter 1}
blablablablabla

\end{document}
```

Comment: It depends on the type of document you are writing I guess. If it is a thesis, your university may provide you with some guidelines.

Comment: no it doesn't. It is a thesis, but 1) latex thesis is something really un-common in my university, 2) university doesn't provide any guideline at all (you can choose your style).

Comment: @CCltx Those are the magic words: _you can choose your style_, hence: choose the easiest one!

Comment: I would choose the most beautiful one, but I'm not really sure on what it is. well... everyone has his own idea... but some things are REALLY ugly :P

Comment: I would just make an empty page, and 'skip' a number. So, in my example, page 3 would be completely white, and page 4 would be numbered 4. How could I make this?

Comment: Take your time to select a good thesis/book template  in latextemplates.com, overleaf, sharelatex... and then some more time to decide if  you want to adapt that template to another class(memoir,scrbook,tufte-book,...). This will keep you from getting entangled with every format issue.

Comment: @CCltx -- it's rather unusual for an odd-numbered (right-hand) page to be left blank with the following even-numbered (left-hand) page to be starting a new chapter (unless you are writing in a right-to-left language).  i thought that a completely blank "blank" page was the default with the `report` class.  it may be overridden using `fancyhdr` but in that case, the `fancyhdr` documentation should contain the instructions for how to restore this default.

Comment: Get a real book and start counting the page while turning them. Pretend one page is empty. You still have to count it. It is there. Just because it is blank, it is there. Skipping a number will confuse your document.

Comment: You are new and don't have much time. Get an introduction to LaTeX and invest one day in reading it. Don't use templates. It is not worth it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, typographic rules prefer blank pages to be really blank. There's a small package for this: `emptypage`.

Another possibility, if you use the `titlesec` package to customise your sectioning commands, you can load it with option `[clearempty]`. In this case, you might also want to use its companion package `titleps` rather than `fancyhdr` (load titlesec   with option `[pagestyles]`), as it's simpler to use since it does not require fiddling with the `marks` system.